# Enable JavaScript inside Java Applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet

So, I have made a proxy-like Java Applet. It lets you navigate a site, handling cookies an everything, and supports authentication on the remote site. The thing is that after logging in on the remote site, I try to navigate by clicking the links and it complains that I have JavaScript disabled. To clarify, the site is functioning perfectly well when accessed directly.

My question is, can I somehow enable JavaScript inside my applet? Is it something that has to do with the browser, is it some HTTP header I must include? Am I missing something in the picture..?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Please show some code. For example, what are you using to navigate the websites?

Comment: You need a complete JS-enabled web component.

Comment: I am using a Java Applet combined with JSP to create a simple interface: it's all basically contained inside an iframe. The source of the iframe is a temporary file generated automatically which contains the processed HTML of the response of the remote server. So, I am executing POST and GET requests from my proxy, and any response I receive, I dump into a file which is then displayed inside the iframe.
Unfortunately there is no way to display the code without breaching company rules, so I am unable to post it here...